# How do I get a the JSON array when it starts with an array but has no name for it?

Tags: arrays, json, android-studio

I want to access the array and get the text portion but it starts like this and I don't know how to get inside the array to get the text portion of it.

```
[
{
    "textProns": [],
    "sourceDictionary": "ahd-legacy",
    "exampleUses": [],
    "relatedWords": [],
    "labels": [],
    "citations": [],
    "word": "car",
    "partOfSpeech": "noun",
    "attributionText": "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition",
    "sequence": "0",
    "text": "An automobile.",
    "score": 0
}]
```

This is what my code looks like

```
public static String parseJSONForDefinition(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

    JSONArray array ;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. with  com.org.json package

   String inputJson="[  {   \"textProns\": [ ],   \"sourceDictionary\": \"ahd-legacy\",   \"exampleUses\": [ ],   \"relatedWords\": [ ],   \"labels\": [ ],   \"citations\": [ ],   \"word\": \"car\",   \"partOfSpeech\": \"noun\",   \"attributionText\": \"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition\",   \"sequence\": \"0\",   \"text\": \"An automobile.\",   \"score\": 0 } ]";

   ```
   JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(inputJson);
   System.out.println(((JSONObject)arr.get(0)).get("attributionText"));
   ```
2. With Jackson fasterxml api

   String inputJson="[  {   \"textProns\": [ ],   \"sourceDictionary\": \"ahd-legacy\",   \"exampleUses\": [ ],   \"relatedWords\": [ ],   \"labels\": [ ],   \"citations\": [ ],   \"word\": \"car\",   \"partOfSpeech\": \"noun\",   \"attributionText\": \"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition\",   \"sequence\": \"0\",   \"text\": \"An automobile.\",   \"score\": 0 } ]";

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
   ArrayNode arrayNode=(ArrayNode)mapper.readTree(inputJson);
   System.out.println(arrayNode.get(0).path("attributionText"));
   ```